# Projection map of a vector bundle induce isomorphism on top cohomology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I'm reading a passage in Milnor-Stasheff about Euler class, and I noticed that he states that the projection map $$\pi \colon E \to B $$ where $(E,\pi,B)$ is a n-dim vector bundle, induces a canonical isomorphism 
$$ \pi^* \colon H^n(B) \to H^n(E).$$

Clearly by the fact that we have $\pi\circ s_0 = Id_B$ we have that $\pi^*$ is injective. But I have no idea on how to prove surjectiveness.

Can someone help me?

Comment: $\pi$ is a homotopy equivalence, so it induces an isomorphism on all homotopy-invariant things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $F: E\times [0,1]\to E$ defined fiberwise by $(b,x)\mapsto (b,tx)$ is  continuous and is a deformation retraction from the identity on $E$ (in $t=1$) to $B$ (in $t=0$), where $B$ is identified with the zero section of $E$. A deformation retraction induces cohomology isomorphism.

(For the other direction, as the identity on $E$ and the projection to $B$ are homotopic, so $s_0 \circ \pi: E\to E$ is homotopic to $\mathrm{id}: E\to E$ and therefore $\pi^*$ is surjective.)

Comment: Just a minor remark, is it better to define the map $F$ as $e \to t\cdot e$ where $e \in E$? because I've trouble proving that your map is well-defined, (my interpretation is that you used a local bundle chart to represent $e$ as $(b,x)$, but what happens if you choose another chart?

Comment: @Riccardo Yes, $e\mapsto t\cdot e$ is cleaner. By $(b,x)$ I meant the element of $\pi^{-1}(b)$. It seems to me that using Milnor/Stasheff definition of a vector bundle, there is no difference. By that book, a vector bundle consists of a map $\pi: E\to B$ and a vector space structure on each $\pi^{-1}(b)$ so that, for any $b$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ and a homeomorphism $h: U\times\Bbb R^n\to \pi^{-1}(U)$ so that (page 13) "*for each $b\in B$, the correspondence $x\mapsto h(b,x)$ defines an isomorphism between the vector space $\Bbb R^n$ and the vector space $\pi^{-1}(b)$*".

Comment: ah clear! I though you want to use some trivialisation on each fibre! (well deserved +1 now)